# How apps store refresh tokens securely?

Tags: database, redis, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I came across the CodeSandbox GitHub App (https://codesandbox.io/blog/introducing-the-codesandbox-github-app) and noticed that one of its core features is the ability to comment on pull requests. This led me to ponder about the methods these types of apps use to access the GitHub APIs on behalf of users. I surmised that it is likely that these apps hold `refresh tokens` as a means of making API calls on our behalf. This has prompted me to inquire about the best practices for storing `refresh tokens` on the server-side. Is encryption/decryption a viable option for storing them in databases such as Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is a viable option for storing refresh tokens in databases such as Redis. When the tokens are encrypted, they will be stored as ciphertext, which is unreadable to anyone who doesn't have the encryption key. It's important to use a secure encryption algorithm and to keep the encryption key separate from the rest of the application.